# Cannot open another page

Tags: html, css

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JF9D.png)

I'm making a Kakao talk clone for study purposes.

When I click on the button, I can't see anything on my website.

Source: https://github.com/fatejin/kakao-clone-v2.git

Comment: add specific code where your getting an issue.

Comment: Add a piece of code, if your links goes down all the context of the question will be lost

Comment: ok, I appreciate of your words. next time, i do. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The login button is trying to do a submit to friends.html page and that page doesn't exist in your repo so you're getting a 404 (page not found). If you create a friends.html page then clicking the login button will redirect to there.

```
<form action="friends.html" method="get" id="login-form">
  <input name="username" type="text" placeholder="Email or phone number" />
  <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
  <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
  <a href="#">Find Kakao talk Account or Password</a>
</form>
```